# circuit equations derivation problem

Tags: capacitance, inductance

I'm trying to derive from scratch the differential equations that characterise [Chua's circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/m673cc/chua-circuit-diagram/).

[image: CircuitLab Schematic m673cc]

[Here](http://imageshack.us/a/img822/8892/diffeqwithdim.png) are the ODEs I obtain from that diagram. Current is positive if conventional current goes + → –.

[equations http://imageshack.us/a/img822/8892/diffeqwithdim.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img822/8892/diffeqwithdim.png)

This thing is, wherever I look, the IL term in the dV2/dt equation is positive instead of negative, with everything else effectively the same. (Also, beta is generally positive).

Why am I getting the sign of that IL term wrong?

Comment: Can't see the equations ... seems to be an imageshack problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting the sign of that IL term wrong?

The voltage across an inductor is related to the current through the inductor as follows:

\$v_L = L \dfrac{di_L}{dt} \$

where the reference direction for the current is *into* the positive labelled terminal.

[image]

Since:

\$v_L = V_2 \$

it immediately follows that

\$\dfrac{di_L}{dt} = \dfrac{V_2}{L} \$

Comment: That would solve the problem, but why is it that most sources used -L instead of L in that first equation?

Comment: @del42z, in circuit theory, you'll only find the equation I give.  That's because of the so-called passive sign convention (PSC).  In physics, you'll often find the equation for the *emf* of an inductor and that has the opposite sign.  For example, look at the last equation on this page:  http://faculty.wwu.edu/vawter/PhysicsNet/Topics/Inductance/Inductance.html  The key thing to note is that, using a voltmeter, you'll measure the voltage across the inductor, not the emf.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, as the voltage has to balance the emf of the inductor, and that voltage is what is measured. Thanks.